# How to get Json array back from server

Tags: ajax, json

I have code like that

```
function loadAjaxData(code) {
$.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'loadData.html',
                dataType : 'json',
                data : {
                    "limited_num" : limited_num,
                    "search_bunrui_code" : code,
                    "orderType" : orderType,
                    "search_base_date_from" : search_base_date_from,
                    "search_base_date_to" : search_base_date_to,
                    "compare_date_from" : compare_date_from,
                    "compare_date_to" : compare_date_to
},
success : function(data) {
},
});
```

As i know data above is to pass param to server. and in the server it return for me an array object of Json
The question is how can i get that array in the success
Thank for any help

here is the code in the server

```
 @Result(name="loadData",type="json"),

public ArrayList<OrderDeliverAmoutReturnList> returnList;

@Action(value="loadData", results = {
                @Result(name="loadData", type="json", params ={"includeProperties", "returnList"})
            })
    public String loadData() throws Exception{
        OrderDeliverAmoutSearchTO searchTo=this.setCondition();
        returnList=bunruiSummaryService.getBunruiSyouhinShopDayList(searchTo);
        total=this.caculateTotal();

        return "loadData";
    }
```

Comment: You can create the data array outside the ajax call. Name it differently.

Answer (score 1):

if you are sending json data with json type header from server then you can get json object directly in data variable inside success method.

for text/html header of server you can use.

```
var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(data)
```

to get json or array in jsonObject .

Comment: when i do that i have an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.8.3.js:514
jQuery.extend.parseJSON". Sorry i am not good at ajax and json

Comment: it means the json or array which is sent from a server can not be parsed. can you provide the response you are sending from server.

Comment: I dont know much about actionscripts. but can you please provide response data? you may get it from web console of your browser in network panel.

Comment: it return the whole html data. i did not see any json hix :(

Answer (score 0):

It's in the `data` variable in the success callback: `function(data) { }`

Answer (score 0):

here,'data' is itself the json object. if it is array, you can use it like

```
success : function(data) {
  for(int i=0;i< data.length;i++){
    alert(data[i]);//use it
  }
}
```